# String replacement to variable

Tags: arrays, parsing, powershell, powershell-2.0

I've got the following script that works and I'm trying to rewrite in a more efficient manner. The following lines of code below work and accomplish what I want:

```
Get-Content "C:\Documents and Settings\a411882\My Documents\Scripts\printserveroutput.txt" | Select-String -SimpleMatch -AllMatches -Pattern "/GPR" | % {
    $_.Line -replace '(?:.*)(/GPR)(?:.*)(?<=on\s)(\w+)(?:.*)', '$1,$2'
}

Get-Content "C:\Documents and Settings\a411882\My Documents\Scripts\printserveroutput.txt" | Select-String -SimpleMatch -AllMatches -Pattern "DV6" | % {
    $_.Line -replace '(?:.*)(DV6)(?:.*)(?<=on\s)(\w+)(?:.*)', '$1,$2'
}
```

I repeat the same exact lines of code seven times with slightly altering what I'm looking for. The output that I get is the following, which I'd want (note: this is just a small output):

```
/GPR,R3556
/GPR,R3556
```

While this works, I really don't like how cluttered the code is and I decided to try re-writing it in a more effective method. I've re-written the code like this:

```
$My_Arr = "/GPR", "DV6", "DV7", "RT3", "DEV", "TST", "PRE"
$low = $My_Arr.getlowerbound(0)
$upper = $My_Arr.getupperbound(0)
for ($temp=$low; $temp -le $upper; $temp++){
    $Test = $My_Arr[$Temp]
    Get-Content "C:\Documents and Settings\a411882\My Documents\Scripts\printserveroutput.txt" | Select-String -SimpleMatch -AllMatches -Pattern $My_Arr[$temp] | % {
    $_.Line -replace '(?:.*)($Test)(?:.*)(?<=on\s)(\w+)(?:.*)', '$1,$2'
    }
}
```

The output that this gives me is the following:

```
10         Document 81, A361058/GPR0000151814_1: owned by A361058 was printed on R3556 via port IP_***.***.***.***.  Size in bytes: 53704; pages printed: 2                                                                  20130219123105.000000-300  
10         Document 80, A361058/GPR0000151802_1: owned by A361058 was printed on R3556 via port IP_***.***.***.***.  Size in bytes: 53700; pages printed: 2                                                                  20130219123037.000000-300
```

This is almost correct however the -replace line is where my error is occurring since the code is expecting a string instead of variable when it reaches ($Test). It is posting the entire line of the text file that I'm parsing each time that I find /GPR in this example, rather than the desired output shown above. Would anyone know of a method to fix this line and get the same output as the original code I was using?

EDIT: the output that I'm getting right now with the newer code is also the exact text that is in the .txt file I'm trying to parse through. There's more lines than that in the .txt but for the most part it is identical to that. I'm only concerned with getting the /GPR or any of the other possible strings in the array and then the server name which comes after the word "on" each time.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the original text that being matched?

Comment: The output that you get from the second line of code is exactly the original text that is being matched. Sorry, should have mentioned it to be more clear.

Comment: I don't understand what "the second line of code" means.  You're reading input from a file I don't have.....

Comment: Nevermind.  I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is caused by the simple quotes, which prevent variable expansion.
PS is trying to replace the exact string `'(?:.*)($Test)(?:.*)(?<=on\s)(\w+)(?:.*)'` without replacing the $test variable by its value.
Try replacing them with quotes, but keep simple quotes on the second string, as follows:

```
Get-Content "C:\Documents and Settings\a411882\My Documents\Scripts\printserveroutput.txt" | Select-String -SimpleMatch -AllMatches -Pattern $My_Arr[$temp] | % {
    $_.Line -replace "(?:.*)($Test)(?:.*)(?<=on\s)(\w+)(?:.*)", '$1,$2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work on your data?

```
$file = 'C:\Documents and Settings\a411882\My Documents\Scripts\printserveroutput.txt'
$regex = '(?:.*)(/GPR|DV6|DV7|RT3|DEV|TST|PRE)(?:.*)(?<=on\s)(\w+)(?:.*)'
(Get-Content $file) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1,$2'
```